# how to add notifications Automatically?

Tags: android

I have 3 notification now I have task to add notifications every 5 min like loop or with for function I don't know . How that is possible to add automatically notification 4-5-6-7-8-...... every 5 min.

Main Activity..!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);


            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 102, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            final AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            final AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent);
            alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent1);
            alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent2);


        }
    });

}


protected void onStart() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
   // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 102, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent);
    alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent2);

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
 //   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 102, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent);
    alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent2);

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Recivier.class

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,Activity12.class);
//    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("AAA")
            .setContentText("BBB");
          builder.setAutoCancel(true);


        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,101,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(pendingIntent1)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("CCC")
                    .setContentText("DDD");

            builder1.setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager notificationManager1 = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager1.notify(101,builder1.build());            }
    },1* 60 * 1000);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,102,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(pendingIntent2)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("EEE")
                    .setContentText("FFF");
            builder2.setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManager notificationManager2 = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager2.notify(102,builder2.build());
        }
    },2*60*1000);
```

Activity that shows when I click on the notification.

```
public class Activity12 extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_12);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {

    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),AlertReceiver.class);
   // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent2);

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),AlertReceiver.class);
 //   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),102,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent2);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: I don't know how to add notification automatically i need help.! the code is working

Comment: except that the notification still appears when the user enters the App and i don't know how to cancel it (cancel code not working)

Comment: **IF NOOO ONE KNOWS THE ANSWER DON'T GIVE DOWNVOTE :@ **

Answer (score 1):

You should use background service that will executes after every 5 minutes

```
public class TimeService extends Service {
    // constant
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds

    // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // timer handling
    private Timer mTimer = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // cancel if already existed
        if(mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Enter your notification code here to get notification after every 5 minutes
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDateTime(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
        }

        private String getDateTime() {
            // get date time in custom format
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss]");
            return sdf.format(new Date());
        }

    }
```

Call the service from Mainactivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startService(new Intent(this, TimeService.class));
}
```

In you manifest add this

```
<service android:name=".TimeService"/>
```

Comment: when i put my notification creator inside the handler context gives me error even if i write Context context;

Comment: set Context context=getApplicationContext()

Comment: i run the app i still have my 3 notifications noting more :( and how this class defines time ??

Comment: sry i will post it as soon i get my laptop back sry again

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) in which you can place the code for launching the notification. You will need to put the specific logic regarding which notification should be launched. You can set the repeating schedule as shown in the example in the above link.

Comment: my problem I don't know how to add notification automatically like i said i have 3 notification how i can for example 100 notifications and each of them different from the other and appears after 5 min

Comment: Check my answer dear

Comment: it's weird that know one knows :(

Comment: most likely people are not getting what you are trying to do. It's difficult to understand that from your code... I have never seen so many alarmmanager set and then canceled. You have canceled alarmmanager in onPause and then create again in onStop. Which gets canceled again in onResume. This is not how it works. Please read up on notification again.

Comment: how about if i tell you autocancel doesn't work and flag_cancel neither at least OnStop and OnDestroy i get my notifications